# How to get all the indexes of an array that are below a specific index?

Tags: php, arrays

For example, this is an array:

```
$array = array(

    'firstIndex' => 'Tom',

    'secondIndex' => 'John',

    'thirdIndex' => 'Cavanagh',

    'fourthIndex' => 'Gustin',

    'fifthIndex' => 'Stephen',

    'sixthIndex' => 'Amell',

    'seventhIndex' => 'Robbie',

    'eighthIndex' => 'Cisco'

);
```

Is there any way I can get all the indexes after the 'fourthIndex' key? Like this:

```
$someVar = array_get_indexes_after_key('fourthIndex', $array);
var_dump($someVar);
```

would return:

```
array(4) {
["fifthIndex"]=>
string(7) "Stephen"
["sixthIndex"]=>
string(5) "Amell"
["seventhIndex"]=>
string(6) "Robbie"
["eighthIndex"]=>
string(5) "Cisco"
}
```

How do I do this? Any suggestion is genuinely appreciated.

Comment: `$result = array_slice($array, array_search('fourthIndex', array_keys($array))+1);` If you used enumerated indexes, this would be a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

Assumed your named index is always the same, you could use [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) with an offset.